# $setOnInsert doesn't work with bulkWrite in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have millions of record in source collection, I am trying to perform operation `bulkWirte` with `$setOnInsert`, like if incoming record already exists in destination collection then just skip it.

But somehow this operation is not working, I don't know if there is change in behavior of `$setOnInsert` or it doesn't work in bulk update case.

If I perform same operation without `bulkWrite` then its working as expected.

This is code part of code where I tried with batch update

```
bulkArr.push({
    updateOne: {
        filter: {
            date: { $gte: new Date(from).getTime(), $lte: new Date(to).getTime() }, "uid": mergedObj.uid, "baseId": mergedObj.baseId,
            "lessonId": mergedObj.lessonId, "pageId": mergedObj.pageId, "site": mergedObj.site
        },
        update: {
            $setOnInsert: mergedObj
        },
        upsert: true
    }
});
if (bulkArr.length % batchSize === 0) {
    batchCounter = batchCounter + 1;
    stream.pause();
    db.collection('saq_temp_jan').bulkWrite(bulkArr, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            bulkArr = [];
            console.log('Upserted count>>>', result.nUpserted);
            console.log('Matched count>>>', result.nMatched);
            console.log('Batch counter>>>', batchCounter);
            stream.resume();
        }
    });
```

Any suggestion would be most welcome.

Comment: what is the output results? It should works

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon The output, like duplicate record should not updated or inserted in destination collection, if matches the filter. Example; if same date record already exists in `saq_temp_jan` collection then upcoming record should be ignored

Comment: Clear, I mean the `result` variable from the callback